# Excel 2013 with Visual Studio 2013 taking long time to generate excel file

Tags: visual-studio, migration, interop, excel-2013

Initially, My project was developed on MS 2003 with Visual Studio 2005 and MS Office 2007. It takes 5 - 6 minutes to create excel file with microsoft.office.interop.excel

Now, I have migrated my project on MS 2008 R2 SP1 with VS 2013 and MS Office 2013.  For the same sheet above mentioned, it takes around two hours.

Following things I have tried:

1. Latest assemblies have been tried.
2. excelApp.Visible = false;         excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;         excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false; (thse set up are not done before migration but was still fast)
3. Tried installing Excel 2007, Excel 2010 and Excel 2013. (Both Office 32 bit and 64 version tried)

It's being more than 5 days, I am at the same problem.

```
Sample Code is as below:

 Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();       
       excelApp.Visible = false;
        excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        Excel._Workbook excelBook = (Excel._Workbook)excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)excelBook.ActiveSheet;
        Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet2 = (Excel._Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, excelWorksheet, 1, Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet3 = (Excel._Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, excelWorksheet2, 1, Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet4 = (Excel._Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, excelWorksheet3, 1, Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet5 = (Excel._Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, excelWorksheet4, 1, Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet6 = (Excel._Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, excelWorksheet5, 1, Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Excel._Worksheet excelWorksheet7 = (Excel._Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, excelWorksheet6, 1, Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);

        //******************  For the Day Summary Report (Sheet 1)*****************   

        Excel.Range oRng1;
```

... onwards updating excel sheets....

I dont know how to fix it.

Please help.